# Whats's the difference between --print-code and --print-bytecode in node.js command prompt?

Tags: node.js

In the node.js command prompt, I'm typing the following commands:

```
    node --print-bytecode script.js
```

The above line generates a huge bytecode of the program which I get.

```
    node --print-code script.js
```

The above also generates a some sort of similar code but not the same and it's shorter in length as compared to the last command.

I wonder what's the difference between the above 2 commands.

Any help or pointers to reference materials is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand, the first is the intermediate bytecode that can be run on different platforms/architectures. The other is the optimized machine code that results from JIT compilation on the specific machine you run it on

Answer (score 0):

`--print-bytecode` Print bytecode directly to your console.

`--print-code --print-code-verbose` Prints even more information for the code but has no filter for function name.

`--print-opt-code/--print-opt-code-filter` Prints optimized code (really hard to read).

`--trace-turbo/--trace-turbo-filter` Prints optimization filter for TurboFan compiler.

`--print-ast` Prints Abstract Syntax Tree from your code (v8-debug only).

You can read more about it in this [article](https://medium.com/@drag13dev/https-medium-com-drag13dev-how-to-get-javascript-bytecode-from-nodejs-7bd396805d30)